# Doubt about findind a reference about the following extending a pullback into two exact sequences involving cokernels.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

In an abelian category, lets have the following pullback diagram

$$
\array{
Z' &\stackrel{g'}{\to} & X 
\\
\downarrow^{f'} &&\downarrow^{f}
\\
Z' &\stackrel{g}{\to} & X. 
}
$$

I already proved in three pages by hand that we can complete the last diagram to the following commutative and exact diagram

$$
\array{
Z' &\stackrel{g'}{\to} & X &\stackrel{\pi '}{\to} & Coker(g') &\to & 0  
\\
\downarrow^{f'} &&\downarrow^{f}  &&\downarrow^{h} 
\\
Z' &\stackrel{g}{\to} & Y  &\stackrel{\pi '}{\to} & Coker(g') &\to & 0 . 
}
$$

where $h$ is a monorphism. I needed this result for some other result but Im not sure if there is a book or text where I can reference this one? I didnt find in Rotman's Homological algebra or neither other homological algebra. Also wondering if for the dual for an initial push out diagram the morphism $h$ between the two kernels should be epimorphism or it is still monomorphism?

Comment: Well, statements like this are typically very straightforward to check for modules, so you can cite the Freyd-Mitchell embedding theorem.

Comment: Thanks! But It was so hard to prove this for me :(... almost 4 pages. Wondering if there is an easier proof as its not straightforward. So Im looking for a reference so I can only mention it without writing my 4 pages proof . Its hard cause we are asking $h$ to be an monomorphism and epimorphism for the dual :/ @EricWofsey